# Why we use hashmap when only one key can have one value?

Tags: hashmap

What is the use of hashmap when we can associate only one value to one key. We can directly search for that value insted of searching for the key..? am i right..? If not than please explain.

`Key1---2->5->8->2;
Key2---->15->14;
Key3---45->15->10;`
If it will be like this we can search values using key with less no. of iterations.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Wild guess: In your example you have to `15` in different locations and you seem to use chaining. In this case your example is simply wrong, both `15` would end up under one of the keys and so to find all `15`s you have to look only at one key and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It comes in handy when you know the key of the value you need. If this is the case, the search time is constant (doesn't vary with the size of the array).  Yes, you can search the array, but you'd have to iterate it,  which leads to a linear delay (the greater the array, the longer it would take to find the needed value)

Comment: import java.util.HashMap;
public class JavaHashMapExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap hMap = new HashMap();
    hMap.put("One", new Integer(1));
    hMap.put("Two", new Integer(2));
    Object obj = hMap.get("One");
    System.out.println(obj);  
  }
} Can i associate more than one integer to key  :"ONE" or "Two" in this example..?